# Android Studio - No Settings in Design Palette

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently invalidated caches and restarted Android Studio 3.1 as the upgrade from 3.0.1 to 3.1 gave me gradle build errors and another answer on here suggested that method.

My gradle will now build however the design palette doesn't show a preview, and the settings are all blank or null, or along those lines.

How do I get the design preview back?

*Design Palette Screenshot*

[image: Design Palette Screenshot]

*Tool Windows*

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try:**

> View -> Tool Windows -> Preview

Try to **rebuild** or **clean** project. You can also **restart android studio**.

Comment: Preview isn't there

Comment: Clean rebuild and restart

Comment: Preview is not available there and every time restart is not a solution.I have clean and rebuild the project more than 10 times and once restart but did not work

Comment: @justchill It is may be android studio problem. try invalidate and restarrt once

Comment: @justchill then there is only one option you need to start with a new project. try it once.

Comment: I have started a new project in android studio and designing its first page.but the preview design does not show the design and after restarting some time it shows and sometime not