# Android studio 3.1 XML preview not showing for some XML layouts

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

Some layouts are shown, some just have blank, gray frame. I can't seem to find a correlation between XML layouts that work and those that do not, there is a mixture of use of binding, constraint layout, varied in complexity and length, error-free. The app is compiling and running well.

Any suggestions?

Clearing cache/restarting, cleaning, rebuilding had no effect on this

Solution: Noticed a red error icon next to layout in preview mode. It had something to do with id resources resolver @1 . I manually edited one of resource ids on a layout. This somehow fixed issue with rest of the layouts. Weird.

**Edit**: It seems that problem keeps reoccurring. Changing theme on the preview does however help. I would also try to change preview mode to blueprint if you are having problems.

**Edit 2**: I've went with Android Studio 3.2 Canary 9 and layouts are working as expected without problems. I'm guessing it had something to do with new-old bindings compiler

**Edit 3**: Oh god... problems are not ending. 3.2 Canary 11 uses up all given memory fast while editing layouts and then GC keeps lagging all IDE for me. Need to restart IDE every 30mins. I end up reverting to 3.1.1 and if things are not loading I force refresh layout as it was suggested in below comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512223/android-studio-no-settings-in-design-palette/49512255#49512255

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio - No Settings in Design Palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512223/android-studio-no-settings-in-design-palette)

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that but it didn't work

Comment: same error too.

Answer (score 15):

For me, only "Force Refresh Layout" worked. Restarting, re-building, cleaning didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Yup, I've just discovered this feature as well yesterday with 3.1.1 Works like a charm! Except it's not exactly a solution for why things are not loading in a first place

Comment: That doesn't explain or fix the problems. This problem keeps reoccurring and you need to keep hitting the refresh

Comment: It's probably a bug on AndroidStudio. It'd be great if you could marks this as accepted since this does solve your problem :)

Answer (score 5):

i solved it by changing the below dependency

from

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Comment: Worked for me also, thanks!  That's an hour of my life I'll never get back.

Answer (score 4):

I've tried pretty much everything from above and nothing worked for me.
Then I've downgraded my `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`

```
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
```

**It worked!**
I've changed the versions back to 28 and it is still working.

Comment: Man, thanks so much, I would have never thought that the solution could be that.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your dependency in build.gradle(module)

from

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Layout Screen Not displaying ?

Just Open Styles.xml from --- Res -> Values -> Styles.xml

Replace:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

With:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Your Display will come immediately. This is by just adding Base.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized this problem is from FloatingActionButton. Remove it and the preview works.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried pretty much everything from above and nothing worked for me. Then I've downgraded my compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion

---> compileSdkVersion 27

---> targetSdkVersion 27

and then

---> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
to

---> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Answer (score 0):

Carefully check your layout-file for any incompatibilities
create a new layout and add one textview in that view and check whether it will be working fine or not, sometimes our layout contains error it shouldn't showing, please try this way once and switch to "Design".click "force refresh layout"

Answer (score 0):

for android 3.1.3 I solved it by changing the dependencies

from

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in latest versions of Android Studio. The only way i have found to make it work is using **forcing refresh layout** .

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked by changing custom tabs to the version 28.0.0
in my build.gradle app

api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

All you had to do is go to styles.xml file and replace your parent theme from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to  `Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Append Base to the default parent style

Answer (score 0):

If you unable to see 'preview' with eye icon on the right of the xml text. You have to enable preview from the view. Follow this:-
 **View -> Tool Windows -> Preview**

Answer (score -1):

Open your `styles.xml` file.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

That was an issue in Android Studio 3.1. Now in 3.4, there are no issues like that.
So, it is recommended to keep up to date the Android Studio with the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

No need to do anything else other than just changing your Layout to LinearLayout in Activity_main.xml