# Android Studio . Design unable to see anything on design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I just installed android studio on my new windows 10. I was previously using on windows 8 and it was working fine. The Issue I'm facing is quite basic yet very important. I cannot see the layout design components. Please view the image it will help you understand better.

[image: Android Studio Screen Shot]

Comment: let me guess, you're using SDK 28? try changing to SDK 27, and see if you get the preview.

Comment: try changing sdk to 25 in preview options

Comment: post your styles.xml here

Comment: post your xml file for better understanding

Comment: you can refer this once: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51686210/5870824

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Constraint position in parent view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="hello World"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the editor click skyblue colored icon,you will get Force refresh layout option at last.

click it .it will refresh the layout.

if wont work

- change the device and themes.
- clean and rebuild project then open the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like bug in `AppCompat` latest version.

Change `AppCompat` library version in `Gradle` :

**At Design Time**

**From**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
```

**To**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

**At Build**

Change `AppCompat` Version back to :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'.
```

by doing this previews will be available for the design and at build you will be using the latest sdk. :)