# XML layout view not the same as emulator view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Currently learning on how to build an android app, my xml file should show the text `Sup doge` in the layout preview but its not showing at all.

Here's the pic:
[image]

However, the text will show when I build the app & run it on an emulator:
[image]

Now I have a problem where I need to constantly build the app just to see any small UI changes in the emulator when I'm supposed to view it in the layout instead.

**UPDATE #1:**

I tried **Invalidate Cache & Restart** which was suggested by @Khemraj & removed the constraint attributes. Also removed the `tools:text="@string/app_name"` part but its still showing blank in the layout preview. It still shows fine when building the app.
[image]

**Update #2:**

Added background color to check. The preview has a problem.
[image]

**Update #3**

Here are gradle folder files:

`gradle-wrapper.properties` file
[image]

`bulid.gradle` file
[image]

`HeadFirstProject01` file
[image]
Anyone can help me fix this problem?

**Solution**:

Thanks to Khenraj's answer, I was using an unstable sdk ver so I had to update it to the previous stable ver & then build & sync gradle again:

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27 //previously was 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.headfirstproject_01.headfirstproject_01"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 27 //previously was 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1' //previously was 28.0.0-rc02
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: you need to change the `app_name` string in the strings folder (I think the issue is at `tools:text =@string/app_name"`

Comment: Try adding background on TextView, problem is preview is not working at all.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=cant+see+layout+preview+androd&oq=cant+see+layout+preview+androd&aqs=chrome..69i57.7711j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: use the attribute **android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"** also as the error is showing on your xml file

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51591251/android-studio-textview-not-showing-in-design-view-layout/51591502#51591502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout preview is not working. Use **Invalidate Cache & Restart** to see preview.

**Suggestion:**

`RelativeLayout` does not support constraint attributes. So remove those redundant constraint attributes from `TextView`.

**Update**

I seen many questions related this on SO. and answer is not one for all guys.

Here are few solutions:

- Downgrade your sdk version. (compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion & support library versions)
- Force refresh layout
- Restart Android Studio

Comment: Did you try setting background on TextView, does that show on Preview?

Comment: check my edit, even tried `Invalidate Cache & Restart` once more

Comment: Sure your preview screen is not working, can you post your build.gradle file?

Comment: added, took screenshots of other files as well just in case

Comment: You should use stable version of 28, for now you can downgrade to version 27. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50833835/6891563

Comment: Ok it works now after downgrading to ver 27. Can you edit your answer so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 0):

In you xml you are using

```
tools:text="@string/app_name"
```

tools:text is very useful when we design our layouts using the designer. What it does is very easy: act instead of android:text, but only in the designer's preview. This means that in your preview you'll see what you've specified in tools:text. This applies to everything starting with tools:. For example, you could also specify which layout the preview has to use to show a recyclerview's item. I guess that your app_name string is empty, and this is why you are not seeing anything in the preview.

Comment: he is also using `android:text="'`

Comment: android:text will apply on the real device. if you use tools:text, it will override android:text in the designer's preview