# Only grey box in Android GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

When I put grid layouts in my xml file, it doesn't do anything but just shows a gray box. Plus, it doesn't have attributes like columnCount or weight. If I drag several view items and put them under the grid layout, I can't see anything.. What should I do here?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle`?

Comment: @Rhee are you visit this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534777/android-studio-3-1-xml-preview-not-showing-for-some-xml-layouts) before or not?

Comment: post your xml code from `content_main.xml` and did you try what @TanveerMunir has suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Implement` below gradle in your `build.gradle` for `GridLayout`.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
```

after Implement just clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

For me just going into rebuild project under build option at the top worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

After Dropping the Layout Click on Build -> Make Project.